# Share Nifi Controller Service

Tags: apache-nifi

How can I share a Controller Service between **process groups**? I built a `DBCPConnectionPool` and use it in a process group. I need it in another process group. In a nutshell, I want one `DBCPConnectionPool` at root and use it in **process groups**.

Comment: you can declare the controller service at root - it works. the only problem when you do template export/import this automatically creates a copy of the root/parent controller service.

Comment: I create a `DBCPConnectionPool` at root but the pool value in `ExecuteSQL` process in a process group cannot see it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the process group in the parent process group of the groups you want to share it in. For example, if you create it on the root group (top-level canvas), it would be usable by any sub-process groups.

Comment: No it isn't work for me. Do you test it? specially by DBCpConnectionPool.

Comment: Ensure you are creating a Controller Service for canvas components by clicking the *Configure* (gear) button on the Operate palette while on the root process group. Configuring a Controller Service via the global "hamburger" menu creates a Controller Service that is only available to Reporting Tasks. This distinction is made clearer in Apache NiFi 1.4.0.

Comment: Thanks @Andy ! your comment is my answer. I create it through Configure button (not burger menu) and is available in all processor groups.